# vtable in polymorphic class of C++ using gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, vtable

How to display vtable using a pointer to base class object having virtual functions?

Comment: Why do you want to inspect the vtable? It is normally considered an implementation the compiler uses for virtual functions.

Comment: Very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549618/

Comment: if using ddd front-end is an option, it automates a lot of the C++ objects display.

Answer (score 19):

Did you try `set print object on` ?

```
(gdb) help set print object
Set printing of object's derived type based on vtable info.
```

Comment: BTW, in lldb this is equivalent to "settings set target.prefer-dynamic run-target". I'm answering this just because gdb is no longer part of Xcode.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been "settings set target.prefer-dynamic-value run-target"

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer - so glad you posted this all the way in 2010!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a sufficiently new version of gdb, you may want to look at the "info vtbl" command (or perhaps it is called "info vtable"; my own version of gdb is not sufficiently new, and so I cannot test the feature out myself).

I only noticed the feature when googling for an answer to this question and I noticed posts to the gdb mailing list circa 2012, notably this one from March 2012:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gdb.patches/73957